# Remove the ability to edit audit messages

Tags: feature-request, chat

I can't think of a decent reason to allow editing audit messages (like ['n messages moved to room'](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/11025053/history) or [topic changes](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/11025123/history)). I have abused it for fun before but it really has no purpose other than joking or obfuscating your actions. For that I think that such messages should be untouchable. Please make them so.

Comment: I too agree. The lounge has made this a cultural thing, but I too find it's better to prevent is, as a matter of honesty/transparency

Comment: Yes. I am myself partly responsible for starting that culture, and I realised I really don't like it.

Comment: Gallery mode change messages are also editable :(

Comment: Great, another bounty expired :(

Comment: Yes, please. It's become systemic in the Lounge to replace "moved to bin" messages with disparaging comments which, while not entirely surprising, is entirely unacceptable as far as I'm concerned. How are newcomers to the chat system supposed to know what just happened to their messages, and how are they supposed to learn from the experience, when it's just suddenly nuked to oblivion and replaced with orphaned hostility?

Comment: In certain cases, this ability would be very useful to hide teams from intruders, by not exposing some secret chat rooms or other repositories. I vote against taking it down.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ what do you mean by "hide teams" and "secret chat rooms"?

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ not quite getting the context... the most common use case for moving messages is to put them into one of the trash cans/rubbish rooms on the site and *away* from where you are - not to move them into active rooms for people to go try and chat in, right?

Comment: @JonClements Sometimes we need to move a few messages to a special trash and we don't want to expose it.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ but prohibiting editing audit messages won't stop that... everyone can still see where they went and the system will automatically invite them to the room once you move them anyway... It sounds like you're wanting chat to act completely differently than using a poor workaround...

Comment: You can't redact them though... just *edit* them and that leaves a history anyway... I suppose it probably cuts out the simplest of trolls...

Comment: @JonClements ugh, maybe my memory has gone wrong. The actions were moving "secret" messages to a secret room, then delete the audit message directly.

Answer (score 19):

A simple way to fix would be to make these messages work like the [ownership change messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=983706#983706). Those are owned by @Feeds, and therefore no one can edit them (mods excluded, of course; s/m/g/).

Comment: oo the subtle subst pun, I wonder if the dogs will hear it